# Why can't I activate gym form

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, openai-gym

I am trying to use openAI gym, and I have installed it following their documentation. Whenever I try to run their basic cart-pole example:

```
import gym
env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
env.reset()
for _ in range(1000):
    env.render()
    env.step(env.action_space.sample()) # take a random action
env.close()
```

But I am always returned an error:

```
 ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ae18def96b83> in <module>
----> 1 import gym
      2 env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
      3 env.reset()
      4 for _ in range(1000):
      5     env.render()

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gym'
```

As well, I have added my location of the gym install to my PATH, just to see if it would help, but it didn't. 
I've also tried activating the gym environment from the shell, using both the system activate command and the conda activate command, but neither of those have seemed to actually activate the environment:

```
PS C:\Users\Bennett> activate gym
PS C:\Users\Bennett> conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\Bennett\Anaconda3
AI_Gym                   C:\Users\Bennett\Anaconda3\envs\AI_Gym
gym                      C:\Users\Bennett\Anaconda3\envs\gym
mlbook                   C:\Users\Bennett\Anaconda3\envs\mlbook
                         C:\Users\Bennett\Miniconda3\envs\nnseries

PS C:\Users\Bennett> conda activate gym
PS C:\Users\Bennett> conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\Bennett\Anaconda3
AI_Gym                   C:\Users\Bennett\Anaconda3\envs\AI_Gym
gym                      C:\Users\Bennett\Anaconda3\envs\gym
mlbook                   C:\Users\Bennett\Anaconda3\envs\mlbook
                         C:\Users\Bennett\Miniconda3\envs\nnseries
```

What can I do to get the cart-pole example to run?

Answer (score 0):

You don't add a Python package to your PATH. That is meant of binary executables, a Python package is not.

I also see you are using conda. You can now just install the Python package with conda, using:

```
conda install -c akode gym
```

https://anaconda.org/akode/gym

Comment: I tried that, and navigated to anaconda.org to search their cloud to make sure the package was in it. It didn't work, and returned me this message "PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - gym"                                                                                                                               I also noticed at anaconda's website that none of the gym packages are listed as usable for windows. Is there no way to run gym on windows?

Comment: Well, if you check their github, they state: "We currently support Linux and OS X running Python 2.7 or 3.5 -- 3.7. Windows support is experimental - algorithmic, toy_text, classic_control and atari should work on Windows (see next section for installation instructions); nevertheless, proceed at your own risk." So, seems best you just get yourself a decent Linux installation if you want to avoid the hassle Windows will bring upon you.